# TypeError: puppeteer.use(...) is not a function when trying to run my code

Tags: node.js, typescript, puppeteer

Here is my code that I currently have. For some reason it was working and I switched it to a new folder and am now getting this error. All the modules were re-installed under the package.json file. Is there anyway of fixing this.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const  get  = require('http');
const  Server  = require('https');
const  pathToFileURL  = require('url');
const path = require ('./path.json');
const shippinginfo = require('./shippinginfo.json');
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const fs = require('fs');
const { prefix, token} = require('./config.json');
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.commands = new Discord.Collection();
const config = require('./config.json');
const puppeteer2 = require("puppeteer-extra")
const webhookClient = new Discord.WebhookClient(config.webhookID, config.webhookToken);
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const cookies = fs.readFileSync('./cookies.json', '');
const RecaptchaPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-recaptcha');
const captchatoken = require("./token.json");
const request = require('request-promise-native');
const poll = require('promise-poller').default;
const StealthPlugin = require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')
const apiKey = config.apikey
var userAgent = require('user-agents');

puppeteer2.use(
  RecaptchaPlugin({
    provider: { id: '2captcha', token: "aa40e25b217d84b26ba0e4b3928bc51d" },
    visualFeedback: true // colorize reCAPTCHAs (violet = detected, green = solved)
  })
)



puppeteer2.use(StealthPlugin())
```

Comment: which line throws that error?

Answer (score -3):

```
puppeteer.use(require('puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth')())
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.